# why ContourPlot3D does not give plot?

Tags: plotting, polynomials

I wanted to plot the intersections using ContourPlot3D in order to observe how do solutions look like, however, the following code does not work:

```
ContourPlot3D[{Sin[a - b] + Sin[a] + Sin[a - d] == 0 && 
   Sin[b - a] + Sin[b] + Sin[b - d] == 0 && 
   Sin[-a] + Sin[-b] - Sin[-d] == 0 && 
   Sin[d - a] + Sin[d - b] == 0}, {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, {d, 0, 
  2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `&&` with commas to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz6bz.png). Increase the points only if you think it is worth it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can plot individually and then call them collectively, like so: `plot1 = ContourPlot3D[{Sin[a - b] + Sin[a] + Sin[a - d] == 0}, {a, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, {d, 0, 2 Pi}];
plot2 = ContourPlot3D[{Sin[b - a] + Sin[b] + Sin[b - d] == 0}, {a, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, {d, 0, 2 Pi}];
plot3 = ContourPlot3D[{Sin[-a] + Sin[-b] - Sin[-d] == 0}, {a, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, {d, 0, 2 Pi}];
plot4 = ContourPlot3D[{Sin[d - a] + Sin[d - b] == 0}, {a, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, {d, 0, 2 Pi}];` and to make them appear all together `Show[plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4]`

Comment: In 3D, 1 equation will give a surface, 2 equations give a 1 dimensional region that can be empty. 3 equations may give a 0 dimensional region, that may also be empty. However, in general, 4  equations do not have a solution.

Comment: @Seyd. Replacing && by commas will plot all the surfaces belonging to the different single equations and not their intersection.

Comment: @DanielHuber Indeed, it is all the surfaces instead of intersection. Could I ask: why in general 4 equations do not have a solution? Thank you!

Comment: @DanielHuber The reason I ask about this is: the solutions to this equations can be obtained by Solve function, which is not empty

Comment: In 3D 2 equations give 2 surfaces, that in general, have an intersection of 1 dim (lines). Of course in a special case they may have a surface in common. If you have 3 equations, every pair of these have 1 dimensional intersections. That these (lines)  from the 3 pair 
 of equations meet in a common point in 3 D only occurs in a special cases. For 4 equations these is even less likely, but it can happen in special circumstances.

Comment: @DanielHuber Got it. Thanks for your explaination! And here, the equations indeed have solutions, however, the code does not give the plot of intersections..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can simplify the original equations by `GroebnerBasis` method.

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
trigs = {Sin[-a] + Sin[-b] - Sin[-d], 
  Sin[a - b] + Sin[a] + Sin[a - d], Sin[b - a] + Sin[b] + Sin[b - d], 
  Sin[d - a] + Sin[d - b]};
polys = TrigExpand /@ trigs /. {Sin[a] -> sa, Sin[b] -> sb, 
    Sin[d] -> sd, Cos[a] -> ca, Cos[b] -> cb, Cos[d] -> cd};
allfuns = 
  Join[polys, {sa^2 + ca^2 - 1, sb^2 + cb^2 - 1, sd^2 + cd^2 - 1}];
gb = GroebnerBasis[allfuns, {sa, sb, sd}, {ca, cb, cd}];
sol = Reduce[gb == 0] /. {sa -> Sin[a], sb -> Sin[b], sd -> Sin[d]};
oldeqns = And @@ Thread[trigs == 0];
neweqns = FullSimplify[oldeqns && sol]
Simplify[neweqns, oldeqns];
Simplify[oldeqns, neweqns];
```

> `Sin[a - b] == Sin[b] + Sin[b - d] && Sin[a - d] + Sin[b - d] == 0 &&  Sin[d] == 0 && Sin[a] + Sin[b] == 0`

```
result = Reduce[
   neweqns && 0 <= a <= 2 π && 0 <= b <= 2 π && 
    0 <= d <= 2 π, {a, b, d}, Reals] // FullSimplify

reg = ImplicitRegion[neweqns, {a, b, d}];
instances = 
  FindInstance[{a, b, d} ∈ reg && 0 <= a <= 2 π && 
    0 <= b <= 2 π && 0 <= d <= 2 π, {a, b, d}, 1000];
AllTrue[oldeqns /. instances, TrueQ]
Graphics3D[{Red, Point[{a, b, d} /. instances]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What is 'Simplify[neweqns, oldeqns]' and 'Simplify[oldeqns, neweqns]' trying do?

Comment: @HJ_dynamics It means that `neweqns` is equivalent to `oldeqns`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns =
  {Sin[a - b] + Sin[a] + Sin[a - d] == 0,
   Sin[b - a] + Sin[b] + Sin[b - d] == 0,
   Sin[-a] + Sin[-b] - Sin[-d] == 0,
   Sin[d - a] + Sin[d - b] == 0};
```

Solving within the `PlotRange`

```
sol = Solve[Join[eqns, Thread[0 <= {a, b, d} <= 2 Pi]],
   {a, b, d},
   Method -> Reduce,
   MaxExtraConditions -> 1] // Simplify

(* Solve::fexp: Warning: Solve used FunctionExpand to transform the system. Since FunctionExpand transformation rules are only generically correct, the solution set might have been altered.

Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

{{b -> ConditionalExpression[a - π, 
    a ∈ Reals && π <= a <= 2 π], 
  d -> ConditionalExpression[π, 
    a ∈ Reals && π <= a <= 2 π]}, {b -> 
   ConditionalExpression[a + π, a ∈ Reals && 0 <= a <= π], 
  d -> ConditionalExpression[π, 
    a ∈ Reals && 0 <= a <= π]}, {a -> 0, b -> 0, 
  d -> 0}, {a -> 0, b -> 0, d -> π}, {a -> 0, b -> 0, 
  d -> 2 π}, {a -> 0, b -> π, d -> 0}, {a -> 0, b -> π, 
  d -> 2 π}, {a -> 0, b -> 2 π, d -> 0}, {a -> 0, b -> 2 π, 
  d -> π}, {a -> 0, b -> 2 π, d -> 2 π}, {a -> π, b -> 0, 
  d -> 0}, {a -> π, b -> 0, d -> 2 π}, {a -> π, b -> π, 
  d -> 0}, {a -> π, b -> π, d -> π}, {a -> π, b -> π, 
  d -> 2 π}, {a -> π, b -> 2 π, d -> 0}, {a -> π, 
  b -> 2 π, d -> 2 π}, {a -> 2 π, b -> 0, d -> 0}, {a -> 2 π, 
  b -> 0, d -> π}, {a -> 2 π, b -> 0, d -> 2 π}, {a -> 2 π, 
  b -> π, d -> 0}, {a -> 2 π, b -> π, 
  d -> 2 π}, {a -> 2 π, b -> 2 π, d -> 0}, {a -> 2 π, 
  b -> 2 π, d -> π}, {a -> 2 π, b -> 2 π, 
  d -> 2 π}, {a -> π/2, b -> (3 π)/2, 
  d -> π}, {a -> (3 π)/2, b -> π/2, d -> π}} *)
```

Verifying the solutions,

```
(And @@ eqns) /. sol

(* {ConditionalExpression[True, a ∈ Reals && π <= a <= 2 π], 
 ConditionalExpression[True, 
  a ∈ Reals && 
   0 <= a <= π], True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, \
True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, \
True, True, True} *)
```

Plotting,

```
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@eqns,
  {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, {d, 0, 2 Pi},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {a, b, d}),
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"],
 Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[8],
   Point[{a, b, d} /. sol[[3 ;;]]]}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@eqns,
  {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, {d, 0, 2 Pi},
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.05],
  Mesh -> None,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {a, b, d})],
 Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[8],
   Point[{a, b, d} /. sol[[3 ;;]]]}]]
```

[image]